# How to implement a large scrollable text view on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have an implementation of a scrollable text view for large strings, however it doesn't scroll.

Here's the XAML:

```
<UserControl  x:Class="WP81.Controls.LongTextControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="sp" Orientation="Vertical">
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

... and here is the code-behind:

```
public partial class LongTextControl : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(LongTextControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var d = dependencyObject as LongTextControl;
        d.OnTextChanged((string) dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue, (string) dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue);
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        sp.Children.Clear();
        var items = ((newValue.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')).Select(s => new TextBlock{ Text = s, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap})).ToList();
        sp.Height = 0;
        sp.ClearValue(StackPanel.HeightProperty);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            sp.Children.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public LongTextControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Expected behavior is that all of the text would be available in the StackPanel, scrollable via the ScrollViewer.

Actual behavior is that the ScrollViewer gives the StackPanel a sort of "elastic" effect, but doesn't actually scroll. I have confirmed via debugger that all of the text has been broken up, placed into TextBlock controls, and all of the TextBlock controls have been successfully added to the ScrollViewer. The last few TextBlock controls cannot be brought into view because the ScrollViewer won't scroll.

It may be coincidence, but the actual height of the StackPanel matches pretty closely the height of the display, even though it should be taller to accommodate all of its contents.

What is needed to ensure that the StackPanel gets the full height of its contents and is properly scrollable?

Comment: Is the UserControl constrained in any way, or is it itself placed into a scrollviewer?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT The UserControl is placed into a "*"-height grid row of another UserControl which is itself a full-page popup. FWIW, I tried fixing the height of the grid row; the behavior remained the same.

Comment: Also, tried simplifying - so that instead of a popup, the UserControl is directly on a page (still within a grid row, either fixed or "*" height) with the same result.

Comment: Problem solved. Turns out it was placed inside another ScrollViewer, I just didn't notice it on prior inspection.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two workarounds for your problem

One is that you can place your usercontrol in a row which has the height **"Auto"** .This will automatically take care of the scrolling issue.

Other work around is to set the **maxheight** property on your user control as per the size of the text. Although this is not an elegant solution but should work.

And the rootcause of this problem is that the parent control, scrollviewer in your case has no limitation of height because of which it doesn't scroll. Hope this helps!